# Download and Install APK Programmatically

Tags: java, android, apk

I´m tying to build an App which is Downloading and Installing an .apk file.

I am building this with the help of [Download And Install App Programmatically](http://www.wepstech.com/download-and-install-app-programmatically/)

I have added all permissions and the provider in the AndroidManifest.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SYNC_SETTINGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES" />

        <provider
        android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/provider_paths" />
    </provider>
```

I have also created the provider_paths.xml in the xml folder and the GenericFileProvider.java next to the MainActivity.java

In my MainActivity.java i wrote the following code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private static final int PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE = 200;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    Button btn_click = findViewById(R.id.btn_click);
    btn_click.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (checkPermission()) {
                UpdateApp atualizaApp = new UpdateApp();
                atualizaApp.setContext(MainActivity.this);
                atualizaApp.execute("https://example.com/apks/my_apk.apk");
            } else {
                requestPermission();
            }
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    if (requestCode == PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE) {
        if (grantResults.length > 0) {

            boolean locationAccepted = grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
            boolean cameraAccepted = grantResults[1] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
            if (locationAccepted && cameraAccepted) {
                UpdateApp updateApp = new UpdateApp();
                updateApp.setContext(MainActivity.this);
                updateApp.execute("https://example.com/apks/my_apk.apk");
            }
        }
    }
}

@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
private boolean checkPermission() {
    int result = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
    int result1 = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);

    return result == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && result1 == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
}

@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
private void requestPermission() {
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
}

public class UpdateApp extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {
    private ProgressDialog mPDialog;
    private Context mContext;

    void setContext(Activity context) {
        mContext = context;
        context.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                mPDialog = new ProgressDialog(mContext);
                mPDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
                mPDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
                mPDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
                mPDialog.setCancelable(false);
                mPDialog.show();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {
        try {

            URL url = new URL(arg0[0]);
            HttpURLConnection c = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            c.setRequestMethod("GET");
            c.setDoOutput(true);
            c.connect();
            int lenghtOfFile = c.getContentLength();

            String PATH = Objects.requireNonNull(mContext.getExternalFilesDir(null)).getAbsolutePath();
            File file = new File(PATH);
            boolean isCreate = file.mkdirs();
            File outputFile = new File(file, "my_apk.apk");
            if (outputFile.exists()) {
                boolean isDelete = outputFile.delete();
            }
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);

            InputStream is = c.getInputStream();

            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int len1;
            long total = 0;
            while ((len1 = is.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                total += len1;
                fos.write(buffer, 0, len1);
                publishProgress((int) ((total * 100) / lenghtOfFile));
            }
            fos.close();
            is.close();
            if (mPDialog != null)
                mPDialog.dismiss();
            installApk();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("UpdateAPP", "Update error! " + e.getMessage());
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        if (mPDialog != null)
            mPDialog.show();

    }


    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
        if (mPDialog != null) {
            mPDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            mPDialog.setMax(100);
            mPDialog.setProgress(values[0]);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        if (mPDialog != null)
            mPDialog.dismiss();
        if (result != null)
            Toast.makeText(mContext, "Download error: " + result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        else
            Toast.makeText(mContext, "File Downloaded", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            installApk();
    }


    private void installApk() {
        try {
            String PATH = Objects.requireNonNull(mContext.getExternalFilesDir(null)).getAbsolutePath();
            File file = new File(PATH + "/my_apk.apk");
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 24) {
                Uri downloaded_apk = FileProvider.getUriForFile(mContext, mContext.getApplicationContext().getPackageName() + ".provider", file);
                intent.setDataAndType(downloaded_apk, "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
                List<ResolveInfo> resInfoList = mContext.getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(intent, PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);
                for (ResolveInfo resolveInfo : resInfoList) {
                    mContext.grantUriPermission(mContext.getApplicationContext().getPackageName() + ".provider", downloaded_apk, Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
                }
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
                startActivity(intent);
            } else {
                intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
                intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_NOT_UNKNOWN_SOURCE, true);
                intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file), "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            }
            startActivity(intent);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

}

At the end i hava created a Button in the layout file with the id btn_click.

But when I run the App and press on Download the only thing thats happens is that the file just gets downloaded and the app shows an parse Error.

Comment: Well that is a lot i would say.

Comment: So the file gets downloaded.  DO you get to the point of installing?  What's the exact error or exception?  If you have it downloaded, did you check to see if the file is an exact match to the original, or if it was corrupted?

Comment: you are calling startActivity(intent); two times. Remove the second one and put inside else condition. It is giving you parse error because you already installed it, you are starting the install intent again hence showing the error. @JojoGIF2001